# How to straighten the sides of a photograph of a frame?

Tags: photo-editing

How can I straighten the sides of a photograph of a frame. I use an old verion of Paint shop pro 5.0. My camera distorts the straight sides of a photo and causes them to curve.

See my photo:

[image]

Comment: I would assume PSP 5 has lens correction of some kind. I'd try that. Couldn't find any documentation for PSP 5 + lens correction, but perhaps it's in the same place as in the more recent versions: https://learn.corel.com/tutorials/lens-correction-support/

Comment: Stand further back when you take the photo. If you are too close you will get barrel distortion. Ideally, you shouldn't use a phone camera for this kind of thing since most have fixed wide angle lenses which distort images when used too close. A camera with a moderate telephoto lens of around 80mm (35mm equivalent) or more is what's usually required.  Get it right in the camera first, then any editing will be minimal.

Comment: I use photo camera Canon SX 220. I took the photo not too close. It helped. Thanks. I did not understand  your recomendation about - "A camera with a moderate telephoto lens of around 80mm (35mm equivalent) or more is what's usually required."

Comment: if paint shop pro has a "pinch" filter tool (sometimes part of a "spherize" type of tool), you could use that with a very low adjustment value on the image *before* you crop it.

Comment: No, 'pinch' does not help.

Comment: @Vitaly - That camera should be fine. On your camera you could just stand back further from the subject, and zoom in to fill the shot. That will reduce the distortion. An "80mm lens (35mm equivalent)" just means a telephoto (zoom) lens with a focal length of 80mm, or it's equivalent as it would be on a 35mm camera, such as a DSLR or interchangable lens camera. So, zooming in with your camera will be equivalent to that, more or less.